# Fade to black for eight seconds (iMovie)

Tags: imovie, macos

I have a clip at the end of my movie that is eight seconds long, but the Cross Dissolve or Fade to Black transition will only let the end transition happen for one second. Trying to increase the duration shows the error: “The clips do not have enough media available to change the length of this transition.”

Comment: make your clip longer than eight seconds

Answer (score 2):

In order to increase the duration of the transition, you can use the "Precision Editor". Right-click on the transition, and select "Precision Editor" in the context menu. Done!